# Meaning of negative time

Tags: kinematics, spacetime, time

Whenever we graph time along a $x$-axis, we graph it along negative and positive $x$-axis both. So what does a negative time mean in the negative case axis? What does the negative sign indicate?

Answer (score 16):

Suppose you work for NASA and are the person who is given the task of announcing the time to the launch of a particular rocket. You will call this time $t=0$, and so five seconds before the launch you will announce "t minus 5..4..3..2..1..ignition". Now this time $t=0$ could have been for example 28th February 12 noon, and everything before that particular event exists on the "negative time" axis, or all points in time before this event.

We do the same thing always in classical mechanics. We can define any point to be $t=0$ and it simply defines what will happen/happened at this point, and everything prior to this point is the past and everything after it is the future.

Consider also a case where we have a position versus time graph, which shows an object with displacement according to the equation $$x(t)=(5t^2+1)\,\mathrm{m},$$ where $\mathrm{m}$ represents metres and $t$ is measured in seconds. You are told its displacement at say $t=1\,\mathrm{s}$  is $6\,\mathrm{m}$. You can confirm this by substituting $t=1\,\mathrm{s}$ into this equation. But now you want to know what was its displacement at $t=-2\,\mathrm{s}$. You can once again substitute this value for $t$ into the same equation and you will know that the object had a displacement of $21\,\mathrm{m}$, two seconds before it reached the axis defined by $t=0\,\mathrm{s}$.

"Negative time" simply means all points in time before a specific event, that we say will happen at $t=0\,\mathrm{s}$.

We do a very similar thing in relativity with [spacetime diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram). In such cases, the spacetime origin is represented by $x = 0$ and $t = 0$ and represents the present time and location of the observer (in that reference frame). Events with $t > 0$ are in the future, and events with $t< 0$ are in the past of this observer.
We can choose the location of the origin to make the solution of a problem as
simple and convenient as possible when dealing with regular dynamics.

Comment: I never before understood that t minus 5 stuff. I always interpreted it as meaning $(t - 5)$, not $t = -5$.

Comment: @lvella you understood correctly, it is a big T for time or L for launch (T-5) or (L-5) in countdowns https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/content/top-5-terms-you-should-know-satellite-launch so t=T-5 or t= L+5 , not T=-5. Launch is planned for L-0 and happens at T-0.  Of course, T could be arbitrarily set to be the origin, as would be done in any plot related to the launch, and t could be negative as in https://www.history.nasa.gov/afj/ap08fj/pics/buildup.gif

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest possible terms, negative time means last year, last month, last week, yesterday, one hour ago, one minute ago, one second ago. It refers to the *past*.

Comment: What news with the scan?

Comment: @Larsaseeidaklaxtarsa, thanks for asking- the scan came back clean this time, now we monitor. next scan will be in 4 months.

Comment: ... implicit assumption $t = 0$ is "now", which is often not the case.

Comment: @comptonscattering, yes, that was implicit.

Answer (score 1):

The convention is that positive time is the future and negative time is the past. If you assume this convention then you can explicitly show that Newton's laws are time reversible or time symmetric.

A ball is thrown.

$y=v_{oy}t  - \frac{g}{2} t^2$

$x=v_{ox}t$

A film of the thrown ball is played in reverse. $t \to -t$

$y=-v_{oy}t  - \frac{g}{2} t^2$

$x=-v_{ox}t$

In both cases, $m\frac{dy^2}{dt^2}=-mg$.

If you watch a film of a ball moving along such a path then you can't tell whether the film is going forward in time or backward. Both motions are consistent with Newton's Laws and nothing looks unusual if time is reversed.

So, yes, it is ultimately a convention, but it is a convention that works. Obviously, you could completely reverse the convention and that would be consistent with Newton's Laws.

Comment: If you're interested in the physics of time then Hans Reichenbach's The Direction of Time and Roger Penrose's Cycles of Time are worth reading.

Comment: And there is a lot more to be said about this kind of time symmetry in physics. Victor Stenger wrote a whole book about it. Timeless Reality. Feynman and Wheeler solved the self energy of the electron problem by assuming that electromagnetic fields propagate from the past. etc.

Comment: "nothing looks unusual if time is reversed."  This doesn't seem consistent with experience.  If throw a tennis ball across a court, it will bounce at decreasing heights until it rolls along.   It's pretty obvious that it looks unusual when played backwards.  How does that fit into what you are saying here?

Comment: @JimmyJames - they are being imprecise or careless in their speech. If the system is lossless then nothing looks unusual if time is reversed. When you bring in friction - like when the ball hits the court ground and loses some kinetic energy - then your point becomes valid. The people who do physics using only math and rarely involve themselves with physical world tend to forget reality has friction. The equations that 'Directions in Physics' is using are nice equations but they do not model friction.

Comment: @EricM Perhaps.  Thermodynamics also seems relevant here.  I guess I'm just trying to understand the claim.  Is it just Netwon's laws excluding such factors?  From prior reading and study, I think there's something to this but I've never been able to square these claims with real experience.  I'm not asserting they are wrong, just that the 'films of motion' that would appear normal played backwards are a very small subset of all such films.

Comment: I was careful to restrict the example to path of the ball. Newton's laws are reversible. If friction comes into it then you will see something improbable happening, but it doesn't violate classical mechanics. If you could look very closely at the atoms then the reverse path of the ball under friction would look like random improbable but possible actions of molecules on the ball increasing its velocity. It would look like purpose. Hans Reichenbach argues that we remember the past because registering instruments can only record information in the direction of increasing entropy.

Comment: @DirectionsInPhysics If I saw a tennis ball started rolling spontaneously, leap into the air and then bounce increasingly higher multiple times, I would have to assume that it was an *unsual* tennis ball e.g. there was something inside of it or that there was something *unsual* about the surface it was bouncing on.

Comment: @JimmyJames - (1/2) Newtons laws say (one of them does, it's been a while since I was at University): "...in the absence of other forces...". They apply in the strict sense to conservative & elastic  systems. If you have behaviour like friction then you have to modify Newton's Laws. Thermodynamics can at least in part be characterized as accounting for friction, but also for some processes that are not reversible. Example: you can let the air out of a compressed air container and on a global level energy is conserved... but you ain't gonna see that air spontaneously re-fill the container.

Comment: @JimmyJames - (2/2) Same for your ball. Every time it hits something it loses a bit of energy to heating up itself and whatever it hits, and likely some energy to sound. Globally the kinetic energy of the ball + heat energy + energy of sound waves is conserved but over the series of collisions there is less kinetic energy and more heat & sound. Heat loss is not 100% reversible, this can be characterized as friction if you want to. So, the ball's behaviour is not reversible. Physicists wave this away by saying the collisions are not elastic, which is fine as long as they say so up front.

Comment: @Directions In Physics - OTOH we have never seen an event where the atoms in a floor collectively conspire to cause the ball to bounce higher! Sure you can say such an event does not violate classical mechanics, but I can say your example has moved out of the realm of classical mechanics altogether once you are looking at individual molecules or atoms.

Comment: You can derive a lot of statistical mechanics from classical mechanics. But Quantum Mechanics is also time symmetric and that can be shown the basically the same way that it's done in with classical mechanics.

Comment: QM is probabilistic though, in the sense that you cannot say a given event will certainly happen. Perhaps an event like all the molecules in the floor conspiring to transfer net positive kinetic energy to the ball. A math model can be time invariant, that does not mean running the clock backward models reality - you will run into the uncertainty principle. You will sometimes run into the sort of problem where the air does not of itself re-pressurize a pressure vessel (can't recall, I think there is a cute name for this example, somebody's "demon").

Comment: @DirectionsInPhysics Maybe you could explain the distinction you see between something being 'unusual' and something being so improbable you won't expect to see it happen it in billions of lifetimes.

Comment: @JimmyJames It is unusual to see some things because entropy increases overall. And our bodies use the fact that entropy increases to store information. We can't store information without energy moving from a usable form to an unusable form. This is because of gibbs free energy.

Comment: @DirectionsInPhysics Yes that seems obvious.  What I'm not getting is why you think "nothing looks unusual if time is reversed" in these scenarios.

Comment: @JimmyJames When I said nothing looks unusual i was referring to the path of the ball and the equation i wrote. But if you did zoom in far very in to the atomic level you wouldn't see anything strange. All the little motions would individually make sense.

Comment: @JimmyJames at small time and space intervals